# Will an async function run, even after exiting the route?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, file-upload

Ex. Lets say I want to upload a file to a web app, and while it uploads, I want to view other pages(routes?) of the web app. Would the async thread continue running essentially after leaving the page?

Edit: Currently, the web app is simple html form on python flask, but id like to move it to react on the front-end. I don't know if anything is aborting the call but for now yes the page is reloading.

Comment: We need more context. Is this in an SPA framework like Angular, Vue, etc? Or in a regular ol' HTML page with a simple script that starts a `fetch`?

Comment: is there anything aborting the call or is the page reloading?

Comment: if the page is reloading - it is possible that there is no client-side routing. Try making react based SPA with client-side routing - that will enable only specific part of the page to be updated once the whole app is loaded.